# How can I have a double Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, request

I have a problem: I'd like to have a double Ajax request, but I can't.
For example I have a page in PHP (rand.php) which returns a random number.
Code:

```
<?php
$rand = rand(0,10);
echo $rand;
?>
```

In an other page I want to create an Ajax request which get a random number from rand.php twice and write it in different div.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
http = new XMLHttpRequest;
function rando(div){
http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = http.responseText;
        }
    }
    http.open("GET","rand.php",true);
    http.send();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div><br />
<div id="div2"></div><br />
<button onclick="rando('div1');rando('div2')">Randomize!</button>
</body>
```

It doesn't work. Help me, please!

Comment: Are you initializing  `http` anywhere? In your code `http` is not defined, so of course "it does not work". OT: You can generate random numbers in JavaScript as well. I suggest you have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started before you continue.

Comment: You say it doesn't work.  Could you describe what *does* happen?

Comment: I'm with Felix. You need to initialize your http object to a new AJAX request object for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as others have pointed out, your `http` is shared between all callers to `rando`.  You should create a new one inside `rando`.

As an aside, that wont work on all browsers.  You need to create a different type of http request object on early versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize XMLHttpRequest every time you want to call rand.php:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function rando(div)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest;
    http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = http.responseText;
        }
    }
    http.open("GET","rand.php",true);
    http.send();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div><br />
<div id="div2"></div><br />
<button onclick="rando('div1');rando('div2')">Randomize!</button>
</body>
```